# Passing Delegate Methods Across Classes/Files

Tags: c#, class, methods, delegates

I have a method in a class in another file that I want to take a dynamic method.  I'm having some difficulty negotiating the setup.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

for example...

File #1:

```
class DoSomethingClass
{
    // define delegate
    public delegate void DelegateMethod();

    public void Main()
    {
        DelegateMethod d = Func1;       
        AnotherClass.CallsDynamicMethod("Test1", d);

        d = Func2;
        AnotherClass.CallsDynamicMethod("Test2", d);

        // will this work?
        // AnotherClass.CallsDynamicMethod("Test3", DoSomethingClass.instance.Func3);
    }


    // candidate methods for delegation
    void Func1()
    {   Console.WriteLine("calling Func1"); }

    void Func2()
    {   Console.WriteLine("calling Func2"); }   

    public void Func3()
    {   Console.WriteLine("calling Func3"); }   
}
```

File #2:

```
class AnotherClass
{   
    public static void CallsDynamicMethod(string words, DelegateMethod dynamicMethod)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a " + words + " to call...");
        dynamicMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you face?

Comment: Comment it out and see. Just pass `Func3` as a parameter.

Comment: I think I'm having issues communicating between files.  I believe I may need to add 'DoSomethingClass.DelegateMethod' to the signature of File2 so that DelegateMethod is defined....Not sure what the best practice is for all this...the code was just a mockup, I don't know if it'll actually work nor how to tie it together with csc haha

Comment: why not use Action<T> delegate instead of your custom one, such a way you do not have to change your method signature

Comment: Make sure you have the required `using` statements in File #2 if your files span across namespaces.

Comment: how would the "Action<T>" be written, if you please?...not sure how to tie it all together in csc, and unity doesn't support namespaces...

Comment: You most likely don't need to make your own delegate, you can just use Action<> or Func<> and it should simplify the syntax quite a bit.

Comment: thanks servy for your input as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this answers your problem

```
 class Program
{
    static void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action a = Method;

        MyClass.SomeMethod(a);
        MyClass.SomeMethod(Method);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public static void SomeMethod(Action del)
    {
        del();
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, Thanks! didn't know about the Action class.
thought I'd also add that one must use 'using System;' or System.Action

Comment: Yep please learn Action<T> and Func<T>. Its very much essential